# Slick slider not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

i have an image stored in my sql and i want to place it in slick slider , why the slider not contain the images in it
,[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRXOA.jpg)

```
function displayImg(data) {

    var imgs = data.pics;
    console.log(imgs);
    for(var j=0;j<imgs.length;j++)
    {
         $('.slider').append('<li><img  src="' + imgs[j].img + '"/></li>'); 
    }
    $(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    slide: 'li',
    responsive: [{ 
        breakpoint: 500,
        settings: {
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
        } 
    }]
});
}
```

//html

```
 <div data-role="content" id="pic">
                    <section class="slider">

                    </section>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the images to your slider container. You are adding them to your wrapper.

Instead of this:

```
$('#pic').append('<li><img  src="' + imgs[j].img + '"/></li>');
```

Use this

```
$('.slider').append('<li><img  src="' + imgs[j].img + '"/></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Images are never stored in the database (SQL databases) you have to store it's URL in the database , example: `localhost:80/files/imgs/myimage.png` and use the link to refer to the image you want.